# How can I rebase 2 topic branches onto a new branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase

This is the current state of my git repository history:

```
--o--o--o--o--o--o--o master
            \
             o--o--o--o--o  topic2
                   |
                 topic1
```

I want to rebase topic1 and topic2 onto master, and make it like:

```
--o--o--o--o--o--o--o master
                     \
                      o--o--o--o--o  topic2
                            |
                          topic1
```

What is the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

```
git rebase master topic2
git branch -f topic1 HEAD~2   # On (rebased) topic2, set topic1 pointer
```

Note that this assumes `topic1` is simply a pointer to the past of `topic2`, i.e., there should not be any commits on `topic1` that are not on `topic2`. (The `HEAD~2` assumes commit history as shown, in reality you would probably want to use a specific commit id. Note how this would also work if `topic1` didn't even exist: as it has no commits of its “own”, the pointer can just be set arbitrarily.)

**Edit**: In this situation, you can alternatively do:

```
git rebase master topic1
git rebase topic1 topic2
```

The end result should be the same as the first option (iff `topic2` contains all of `topic1`'s commits!). This syntax may be easier to understand, but the solutions will differ if `topic1` *does* contain commits that are not in `topic2`. If that is the case the former solution will simply *discard* any commits in `topic1` that are not in `topic2`, while the latter will merge them into `topic2`. Both outcomes are probably undesirable, but in my opinion it is more clear from the first solution what will happen, which is why I put it first.

To illustrate, if your commit history looks like:

```
a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5 - a6 - a7 master
               \
                b1 - b2 - b3 - b4 - b5 topic2
                          \
                           c1 topic1
```

Then the first solution (`rebase`, `branch`) will give you:

```
a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5 - a6 - a7 - b1' - b2' - b3' - b4' - b5' topic2
                               \ master         \ topic1
```

And the second (`rebase`, `rebase`):

```
a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5 - a6 - a7 - b1' - b2' - b3' - c1' - b4' - b5' topic2
                               \ master               \ topic1
```

However, in this case what you probably wanted to get was:

```
a1 - a2 - a3 - a4 - a5 - a6 - a7 - b1' - b2' - b3' - b4' - b5' topic2
                               \ master         \
                                                 c1' topic1
```

The solution for this outcome would be:

```
git branch tmp id_of_b3_commit   # In this case id_of_b3_commit == topic1^
git rebase master tmp
git rebase tmp topic1
git rebase tmp topic2
git branch -d tmp
```

(If you made this into a script, you could use `git merge-base topic1 topic2` to find the id of the commit to put into the `tmp` branch.)

Comment: @bmm In step 2 the branch “topic1” is moved (`-f` to force setting an existing branch) to the commit that is two steps in the past from the current position (`HEAD`, in “topic2” since the first command puts us in that branch). Like it says in the answer, I would suggest replacing `HEAD~2` with the desired commit id from the log (i.e., the id where you want “topic1” to branch off).

Answer (score 1):

If topic 2 is in fact a branch with at least one of it's own commits, then you can do some grafting. But an easier way to do this is to merge topic 1 and topic 2. Now 'rebase --onto' the new place this merged branch with --preserve-merges. Reset topic 1 and topic 2 to where they are supposed to sit.

Answer (score 0):

You may rebase `topic1` and `topic2` branches one-by-one.

Rebase first one

```
git checkout topic1
git rebase master
```

Then rebase second one

```
git checkout topic2
git rebase master
```

But i'm not sure what will be with the `topic1^` point.

I suggest to do it in a little bit more complicated way that will preserve branches merge history.

First make new branch with all commits shared by both topics (you may use commitish or tag instead)

```
git checkout -b topics topic1^
```

Then rebase it on master

```
git rebase master
```

Then rebase both topics on shared branch.

```
git checkout topic1
git rebase topics
git checkout topic2
git rebase topics
```

This should work. Now you may to drop temporary branch.

```
git branch -d topics
```

Comment: re. first part: If you rebase both separately onto master, then you will end up with separate commits for the shared parts of topic1 and topic2. However, if topic1 is just a pointer to the past of topic2, you could do `git rebase master topic1` and `git rebase topic1 topic2`, which should also lead to the same situation as my suggested solution.

Comment: @Arkku, I think your solution in your comment is very simple and it works. In fact, it deserves to be an answer.

Comment: @Arkku +1 for git rebase topic1 topic2. you may edit my answer or i can do it my self if you dont mind to address the perfect solution

Comment: @bmm I expanded my answer to include this option, along with the explanation why I did not initially answer that. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git switch topic2
$ git rebase --update-refs master
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/topic2.
Updated the following refs with --update-refs:
    refs/heads/topic1
```